# Will there be madd if shaddah over yaa is preceded by a kasra

Tags: quran, tajweed

Assalamu alaikum

Will there be madd if there is a shaddah (tashdid) over yaa, and the yaa is preceded by a kasra? Such an occurence is there in the last words of Ayat Al Kursi.

Similarly, will there be madd if there is a shaddah over waw, and the waw is preceded by a damma?

Comment: What do "madd", "shaddah", "tashdid", "yaa", "kasra", "waw", and "damma" mean?

Comment: @justinnoor.io yes I am referring to و هـو العلِيُّ العظيم

Comment: @Rebecca J madd = connective lengthening of words during Quranic recitation, shaddah = an Arabic symbol that indicates the doubling of a consonant (i.e. book-case), yaa = an Arabic lettter equivalent to the English y, kasra = a diacritical mark that indicates a vowel sound, waw = an Arabic Letter equivalent to an English w, damma = a diacritical mark that indicates a vowel sound

Comment: These look to me as two distinct questions. A madd in the given examples seems impossible to me.